# Jquery Accordion Menu with Live Filter

Tags: jquery, menu, filter, show-hide

I've created a menu that works as I need. It shows the menu headers and if you click on it it expands to show the links.

This can be seen working here : **[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jYcLD/)**

I'm using this code to toggle the menu show & hide:

```
$('.slippy').hide(400);
$('a#show').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.slippy');
    $('.slippy').not(elem).hide(400);
    elem.toggle(400);
});
```

What I would like to do is add a filter text box to this, so as I type in, the menu is reduced until I'm just shown any matching results.

So for my example JFIDDLE, I have in my List 2 an entry called 'List 2 Entry 3'

If was to enter that into the search field, then the menu would reduce to just show that one specific menu item. However I have 'ALL' in in List 1 and List 3 show searching for that should return List 1 & List 3 expanded, with all other entries hidden.

On my local PHP server, I've got it partially working. As I type the lists are reduced to just show the ones with the matching entries.  But I can't work out how to have them pre expanded and how to hide the other non matching entries in the matching lists.

The code in this Second **[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jYcLD/1/)** works locally, but doesn't seem to work at JFiddle..

I'm using this to filter the results:

```
function filter(element) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    $("#list > li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
};
```

This is what I'd like it to do, If I search for 'ALL'

[image]

Any help with be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Anyone any ideas on this ?